# How do you check if the user passes at least one of the arguments?

Tags: python, parameters, optional-parameters

Sometimes an object can be constructed by different types of arguments. For example, a circle object can be defined either by providing its radius or its circumference. How do I write the `__init__` method so that it constructs a circle object both when the user enters a radius and when they enter a circumference.

I came up with this but it looks too bloated:

```
class Circle:

    def __init__(self, radius = None, circumference = None):

        # Calculate area when user provides circumference
        if radius is None and circumference is not None:
            self.area = (circumference**2) / (4*3.14)

        # Calculate area when user provides radius
        elif radius is not None and circumference is None:
            self.area = (radius ** 2) * 3.14

        # Raise error if neither radius nor circumference or both are provided
        else:
            raise TypeError("Pass either a radius or circumference argument value")
```

Do you default the parameters to `None` or is there a proper Python way designed for this scenario?

Also, is the use of `TypeError` correct in this case?

I don't even know if radius and circumference are considered optional or required arguments here since at least one of them is somehow required. Can someone enlighten me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just prioritize one of both arguments if two are provided. It would be something like this:

```
class Circle:

    def __init__(self, radius = None, circumference = None):

        # Calculate area when user provides circumference
        if circumference:
            self.area = (circumference**2) / (4*3.14)

        # Calculate area when user provides radius
        elif radius:
            self.area = (radius ** 2) * 3.14

        # Raise error if neither radius nor circumference or both are provided
        else:
            raise TypeError("Pass either a radius or circumference argument value")
```

Comment: Good use of `if x` instead of `if x is not None`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you want the the title question answered:

Your code seems fine, but you could use `**kwargs` parameter instead of listing all possible candidates, which can be checked for containing something easily without going into details.

For the general approach:

I guess your breakdown of functionality adds to complexity: why do the computation stuff in the constructor? Consider this interface:

```
   c = Circle()
   c.setRadius(4.5) # alternatively: c.setCircumference(13.7)
   print(c.getArea())
```